# Angular Webpack SASS "Unknown word" issue

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I have an issue when using SASS interpolation inside an `.scss` file in an Angular 2 application.

**Webpack Config**

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader']
    },
    ...
],
postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%'] })]

...
```

**Sample Code that results in an error**

```
$attr-name: border;
.test {
    #{$attr-name}-color: blue;
}
```

**Resulting Error**

[image]

If I remove the interpolation (i.e. `#{...}`) I don't get the error. I've tried to find out what's the problem but I couldn't find anyone that had the same problem as me.

Comment: me too got similar error when i was having css files. i got it working when i changed css to scss. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2243